# Connection lock with hibernate

Tags: hibernate

In my hibernate application I used both current and open session. I configured the max active connection as 40. When I make 40 concurrent request to application each thread block one connection for current session and all threads are Waiting for one more connection for open session to complete the request. This is how my application gets hung. How can I solve this problem?.

Comment: Then you are not releasing your connections in a timely manner.

Comment: Hibernate itself release the current session  once response is dispatched. For open session I close the connection manually. Problem is for releasing current session I need one more connection. Timely manner means I need to set connection lifetime?

Answer (score 0):

Optimize the thread pool size based on connection pool size is fix my problem. For above case I limit the thread poll size as 30. But is it right solution?.